# How to update libpq.dll to recent Version for php 7.3 (Win x64 binaries)

Tags: php, windows, binaries

Is there a way to update the libpq.dll file shipped within the current 7.3 php binaries? The out of Box one is below Version 10 - but I need at least V10 for SCRAM Support. Perfect would be V13

I've tried to copy over the recent dll from current PostgreSQL\lib\ Folder to php\ but it doesnt work as expected

```
Postgres functions missing, have you compiled PHP with the --with-pgsql option?
```

I am not able to "build from source" because this has to stay maintainable within a reasonable amount of worktime.